# arm_navigation stack

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, ros-fuerte, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly new to ROS and especially the arm_navigation stack and was just wondering if there's a simpler method to determine the inverse kinematics of a custom/undefined manipulator than described in the [Running arm navigation on non-PR2 arm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Running%20arm%20navigation%20on%20non-PR2%20arm), which describes altering the pr2_arm_kinematics stack's services and source to suit a custom manipulator.
I followed the [arm_navigation tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials) and in the [inverse kinematics tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%204) the source requires services "pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_ik_solver_info" and "pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_ik", which I'm sure are only relevant to the pr2 - as is in the description of the pr2_arm_kinematics stack. Likewise with the iROS tutorial and all other's I've found.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The reason I am not a fan of this method is than I have a 5 DOF robot, not 7. meaning I would have to go through several ~500 line source code files to adapt the code. Or I could go the ineloquent task of added 2 fixed joints and nonexistant links

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34752/arm_navigation-stack/) by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-24**:
I have used the Planning Description Configuration Wizard to attempt to set up the IK solver relevant to my robot, but the tutorial [Inverse kinematics for the PR2 arms] uses pr2 services to determine the IK, which is 7DOF, and cannot suit 5DOF.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-24**:
The wizard should setup kinematics for your robot, not for the PR2.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-05-27**:
OK I think I misunderstood the tutorials. It almost works now, just working on a few new problems to do with package dependencies etc. Thanks for the time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should definitely check out the [Planning Description Configuration Wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard) Tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

David Lu's [arm_kinematics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics) package will automatically create an IK solver for your non-PR2 arm. You do not really need to worry about the [inverse kinematics tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%204) you linked to because that is only for PR2 arms. Additionally, I believe the "Planning Description Configuration Wizard" sets up David Lu's IK solver for you.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1